# What does "get to cover" mean?

Tags: meaning

I've seen "**get to cover**" in a Overwatch (a team-based multiplayer first-person shooter video game) cinematic trailer.

I don't understand what **get to cover** means.

Comment: It *could* mean "allowed to provide coverage on", or it might mean, "allowed to perform another's song" or it might mean "Run and hide under something".

Comment: 2:29 seconds of my life that I'll never get back. It means go to a place of safety.

Comment: Why was a dictionary or [Google search](https://www.google.co.uk/search?client=safari&hl=en-gb&ei=lWLrV5z4BKuagAaR7IzoCA&q=get%20to%20cover%20definition&oq=get%20to%20cover%20definition&gs_l=mobile-gws-serp.3...26420.27287.0.28348.3.3.0.0.0.0.254.574.0j1j2.3.0....0...1c.1.64.mobile-gws-serp..1.1.207...30i10k1.hZG2gpygaFg) not good enough? Take the [Tour] and see [ask] to learn about **general references**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, Overwatch is a team-based multiplayer first-person shooter video game.

In that context, get to cover means taking shelter below something so that it would protect the soldier from incoming fire and bomb splinters. For example:

> When you’re sitting in ambush position you want to be sure that the
>   enemy is coming into your fire, if they don’t you have just wasted 2
>   minutes sitting around as a noob, plan ahead and be sure, if you are
>   forced to sit and defend because no one else is helping on the flank,
>   you’re doing the right thing, you don’t want to overextend yourself in
>   such situation, you want a place where you can **get to cover** fast and
>   you’re 100% sure to get the first shot in.

And "take cover" is more commonly used than "get to cover". They both have the same meaning.

Answer (score 0):

In the context of "Overwatch" (a first person shooter), "get to cover" means get behind something so that the bad guys can't shoot you.

Answer (score -1):

getting behind something to be safe. For example: [image: gettocover]

Comment: That screenshot doesn't show anything to people unfamiliar with the term. Moreover, four of those guys are very much not in cover.

Comment: The guy in the back of brown wall is in cover, which is the guy playing right now. First person shooter.

Comment: The guy playing right now is the one who's arms we are seeing. Also very much not in cover.